# Regex to match a section between two static url components

Tags: php, regex

I have a url like so: `http://example.com/c/TEXTTOMATCH/`. The problem is that the url isn't always like that; sometimes it's `http://example.com/c/TEXTTOMATCH/#/?test`. I'm trying to use a regex to grab everything between `/c/` and `/`. I've tried

```
$catpreg    = preg_match('/c(.*)/', $reffer, $matches);
```

but it fails.

Comment: just explode the path on / you are over thinking this

Comment: my problem is that if i explode it I can't then relibly know where in the array the text i want will be

Comment: its  always the 2nd one at least in your examples

Comment: There is a `/` right after `/c` so I suppose you're getting a blank string back? Why not `/c/(.*)/`

Comment: no I'm actually getting Warning:  preg_match(): Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash in now... I' I've checked regex101 and \/c\/(.*)\/ grabs what i want but preg complains

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
preg_match('#/c/(.*?)/#', $reffer, $matches);
```

You were just everything after `c`, not matching the slashes. The slashes in your call were being used as the delimiters around the regexp, I used `#` as the delimiters so I could use `/` inside the regexp without having to escape them.

The non-greedy quantifier `.*?` ensures that it only matches `TEXTTOMATCH` in the second example, not `TEXTTOMATCH/#`.

Answer (score 3):

How about this:

```
<?php
$url='http://example.com/wreqwreqrq/rfqewrqwe/c/TEXTTOMATCH/';
$split_url=parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH);
//print_r($split_url);

$e=explode('/',$split_url);

//find "c" key and add one

$find=array_search('c',$e);

echo $e[$find+1];
```

Comment: ohhhhhhhhhhhh now thats a nice way to do it, won't quite work though becuase I might have another /c/ after the first one and the text to find..

Comment: Yeah, she's a real looker. Just like that waitress gf of mine.